# how to write this query using zend framework?

Tags: mysql, zend-framework

Basically i need to have this query done through zend framework.

```
SELECT k.id AS ID ,k.name AS NAME ,k.ppu_sell AS PRICE, k.type as TYPE FROM `inventory` as k UNION
select m.id AS ID, m.name AS NAME, m.price AS PRICE, 'menu' as TYPE FROM menu as m
```

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1319611/zend-framework-select-objects-and-union

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
    $select = Zend_Db_Table::getDefaultAdapter()->select();
    $select->from(
        array('inventory' => 'k'),
        array(
            'ID'    => 'k.id',
            'NAME'  => 'k.name',
            'PRICE' => 'k.ppu_sell',
            'TYPE'  => 'k.type'));

    $selectClone = clone $select;

    $select->reset()->from(
        array('menu' => 'm'),
        array(
            'ID'    => 'm.id',
            'NAME'  => 'm.name',
            'PRICE' => 'm.price',
            'TYPE'  => new Zend_Db_Expr("'menu'")));

    $select = Zend_Db_Table::getDefaultAdapter()->select()->union(array(
        $selectClone, $select
    ));
```

Answer (score 0):

[Zend Framework Select Objects And UNION()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1319611/zend-framework-select-objects-and-union)

Comment: that is not very helpful. don't consider it duplicate answer. I need it written for idiots cuz i've been troubling my mind here and it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: I'm sorry if you didn't find that link "helpful", however what you accepted as solution was already proposed and accepted there. Therefore, this is a duplicate. Don't say this is not a duplicate because the other question is not *exactly* what you're asking for.